# Understanding a basic program

Tags: c

I'm trying to understand the code below and i'm having a hard time understanding it.
It's very basic for you but for me it's quite a bit complicated. I would really appreciate your answer.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 void fun(int);
 int proc(pf, int, int);

int main()
{
  int a=3;
  fun(a);
  return 0;
}

void fun(int n)
{
     if(n > 0)
   {
    fun(--n);
    printf("%d,", n);
    fun(--n);
   }
}
```

From what I understand fun takes 3 so--> `fun(3)` and then it calls up the function until `n` is not > than 0. so it must store 3,2,1,0 right?

But yet again it prints 0 because 0 is not bigger than 0.

What I don't understand is the `printf` inside the if statement because we're printing if `n>0` so when 0 is not bigger than 0 shouldn't it skip the statement? and return nothing?

I know what it's printing but i'm really trying to understand.

Let me know if my question was clear enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that this will illustrate it:

```
            fun(3)
            ------
              ↓         
           fun(2)  print → fun(1) ..
              ↓
           fun(1)  print → fun(0)
              ↓
           fun(0)  print → fun(-1)
```

Comment: ohh okay because it calls twice

Answer (score 2):

When `n` is 1, control flow enters the if statement, but then `n` is immediately decremented (`fun(--n)`) so it becomes 0.

Comment: okay that i understand but later on it decrements to -1 and returns 1 then 2 then 0. That i don't understand

Comment: @user2985083 the second recursive call is **after** printf, that's why. I suggest you draw the call stack on paper or examine your program in a debugger.